# angular 6 - pass service as object property

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i pass an angular service to as object property to use in another class.

```
    this.setConfig({
  pageName: 'drivers',
  service:  DriverService
})
```

In the example above, im trying to pass the DriverService to a super class. I want to do this in order to dont have to inject the service directly in the class.

Is there any other means to do this.

thank you very much.

Comment: In that case, you will have to paste the injected object, not the class Reference. Paste your component constructor for better answer :)

Comment: You mean like this: `constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public driverService: DriverService
   
  ) {
      service: driverService
    })
  }`. When i do this i can only access the variables defined in the service but not the methods.

Comment: In that case, request you to post the full source code if possible. Edit the question and post the same..